# Wicka-wub a string

Tags: code-golf, string

*Inspired by [this.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39743330#39743330)*

Given a string as input consisting of only upper and lowercase alphabet characters, **wicka-wub** it.

#### How do I wicka-wub a string?

The example text used is "DJMcMayhem".

Split the string before each capital letter, so you get `["D", "J", "Mc", "Mayhem"]`.

Next, take the two halves of the list as sublists. This gives us `[["D", "J"],["Mc", "Mayhem"]]`. If the list is an odd length (i.e. 3), the first sublist will contain the middle substring (i.e. `[[a,b], [c]]`).

Create a list of `wicka`s and `wub`s.  The number of `wicka`s should be as many as the length of the first part of the input list (i.e. `["D", "J"] -> ["wicka", "wicka"]`), and the number of `wubs` should be as many as the length of the second part of the input list.  In our case, this gives `["wicka", "wicka", "wub", "wub"]`.

Now join the sublists of the input list into single strings and flatten.

We currently have `["DJ", "McMayhem"]` and `["wicka", "wicka", "wub", "wub"]`.

Join the `wicka`/`wub` list with `-`s: `wicka-wicka-wub-wub`.  Prepend a `-`.  If there is more than one capital letter in the input, append another `-`.

Now we have  `["DJ", "McMayhem"]` and `"-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-"`.

Append the `wicka-wub` string to the end of the first item in the input list, to get `["DJ-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-","McMayhem"]`.

Lastly, repeat the characters in the second part of the string by their 0-indexed value in the original input string. In our example, that means the first `M` would be repeated twice, then the `c` three times, and the next `M` four times.   Join the list, so the second part (the part you just repeated letters in) is appended to the first part (`"DJ-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-"`).

Final result of input:

```
"DJ-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-MMcccMMMMaaaaayyyyyyhhhhhhheeeeeeeemmmmmmmmm"
```

Total process:

```
["D", "J", "Mc", "Mayhem"] =>
[["D", "J"], ["Mc", "Mayhem"]] => 
["DJ", "McMayhem"] and ["wicka", "wicka", "wub", "wub"] =>
["DJ", "McMayhem"] and "-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-" =>
["DJ-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-", "McMayhem"] =>
"DJ-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-MMcccMMMMaaaaayyyyyyhhhhhhheeeeeeeemmmmmmmmm"
```

### Your task

Your task is, given a string that consists of only upper and lowercase alphabet characters, output the wicka-wubbed version of that string.

### A few rules

- The input may consist entirely of lowercase letters, or entirely of uppercase letters, or any number of each, but no other characters.
- If the input consists of entirely lowercase letters the correct output should simply be the final stage (the string with the characters repeated according to their 0-indexed position). There should be no `wicka` or `wub` in that case.
- Standard rules apply, full programs or functions, up to you.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins.

`GoodLuck-wicka-wicka-wub-GGGGGGGGooooooooollllllllllfffffffffffeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssssss`

### Test cases

```
input => output

DJMcMayhem => DJ-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-MMcccMMMMaaaaayyyyyyhhhhhhheeeeeeeemmmmmmmmm
PPCG => PP-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-CCGGG
foobarbaz => fooooobbbbaaaaarrrrrrbbbbbbbaaaaaaaazzzzzzzzz
FooBarBaz => FooBar-wicka-wicka-wub-BBBBBBaaaaaaazzzzzzzz
HelloWorld => Hello-wicka-wub-WWWWWoooooorrrrrrrllllllllddddddddd
Test => Test-wicka
UPPER => UPP-wicka-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-EEERRRR
fooBarBaz => fooBar-wicka-wicka-wub-BBBBBBaaaaaaazzzzzzzz
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13841/66833)

Comment: Can you add a test with `5` uppercase letters?

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##dVLbboMwDH1uvsIvE0m5dHRvSPsSFE0pTUs2GqIQVG0/zxwgXKSNJ3xsn3Nsx3y7utVvw6AeprUOHsLVhFzlDWyvPxqp766mykkrLo1kBTlY6XqrIUBlzuG4Rq@ckM5Zpe/wDkqb3lFGiLrBBGaqa9qntNQzGUQcjaLss1WaNqpz9CEMXXUT@FEYC32XNE8QoxMLi3OWzIzMf4QYYV2HkiUnt9ZCVQuL8nMNaqEDj6F@b8ysfxibMoGAvtLS5zkjB9l0csmWac5DhS/YSC2G5wkSGDPoZjEzURR@p1klVUP9DFPV6cz43FFu0NM5XqOXc8E5earqSyBblEYQQzSGaXRcynDnbEz0lx2c8@1ewpqXlngkSmCfwCZOwm8Ycr0C3ammPhppGNud5/8yFmZGoY29YGJpWn39@S5WDn/96SFNOxuGXw) is an ungolfed reference implementation in Python

Comment: The formatting at the top hurts my eyes. Can you clean it up a bit?

Comment: @Riker it doesn't hurt my eyes, so I don't know how to clean it up as to not to. Feel free to edit, however.

Comment: Can I use "Wubba Lubba Dub Dub" instead? Doesn't save me bytes though :P.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No, I'm afraid you can't :(

Comment: Doesn't splitting 'foobarbaz' before each uppercase letter return the string unchanged, e.g. ['foobarbaz'].  This list has an odd length and the two halves would be: [['foobarbaz'], []].  So, shouldn't the answer be 'foobarbaz-wicka'? (There aren't any test cases that start with a lower case letter and have an uppercase letter later in the string.)

Comment: @RootTwo hang on, I think that got caught in the mass edit. I'll just put that back in.

Comment: "_the first sublist will contain the odd number (i.e. `[[a,b], [c]]`)_" Actually, now the first list contains an even number of items, not odd. ;) I would change this to "_the first sublist will contain the **middle substring** (i.e. `[[a,b], [c]]`)_", or something along those lines.

Comment: Should `foobarbaz` simply return `foobarbaz`? Is there a second part at all?

Comment: Also suggested test-case: `fooBarBaz`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer please read the second point in the rules

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Well it's a bit unclear...you mean that if the input is all-lowercase instead of the standard procedure we just repeat each char the 1-based index of it times?

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency in how the repeated characters are done. In the test case for 'PPCG', the 'C' is at index 2 and is repeated 2x in the output.  For test case 'foobarbaz', the 'f' is at index 0, but is repeated 1x in the output; the first 'b' is at index 3, but is repeated 4x in the output.

Comment: Not necessarily a problem of the challenge, but I can't solve this as elegantly as I hoped. There seems to be unnecessary special casing to an otherwise interesting challenge, particularly the no-uppercase strings. It's personally turned me away from solving this cool-looking challenge in three different languages. Maybe something to consider for future challenges.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 142 bytes

**130 bytes code + 12 for `-F(?=[A-Z])`.**

This now correctly matches all the test cases provided.

```perl
map$a+=y///c,@E=($z=/[A-Z]/)?splice@F,0,@F/2+.5:();print@E,("-wicka"x@E,"-wub"x@F,"-"x!!@F)x$z,map$_ x$a++,$z?map/./g,@F:('',/./g)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc/RasIwFAbg@zyFloAJTc0YeGMpzXTNxkAoYyIoMtIat2JsQlqx9uGXpXr3/ZzDfzhGWjVz7iwMFGFyo5SWhGUJgn1Cdy/Rdk9x2hhVlZJx8kQYp8/hdDZHODa2qluWERRE16o8iaDzwftSeHGvoBuPGccd7MlQ/z3q/ImQwD71kU7pj2@bo8mEDMYuvtQHeYQidq8fq3Ilbr/yDPJ8@QaOWhfCFqIHXOuFsAuvd6mU3mirDuBLNi1Y53n2OWw@5n/atJWuGxdxlCb3R/AoUv8)

**Note**: TIO includes `-l` to run all tests at once.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 (782 bytes)

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;import java.util.*;import java.util.function.*;public class p{Function<String,String>b=s->{List<String>p=Arrays.asList(s.split("(?=[A-Z])"));if(!s.matches("[^A-Z]*[A-Z].+")){String w="";int i=0;for(char c:String.join("",s).toCharArray()){w+=String.join("",Collections.nCopies(i,Character.toString(c)));i++;}return w;}String h="-";List<List<String>>k;if(p.size()!=1){k=Lists.partition(p,2);String w=String.join("",k.get(0))+h+String.join(h,Collections.nCopies(k.get(0).size(),"wicka"))+h+String.join(h,Collections.nCopies(k.get(1).size(),"wub"))+h;int i=String.join("", k.get(0)).length();for(char c:String.join("",k.get(1)).toCharArray()){w+=String.join("",Collections.nCopies(i,Character.toString(c)));i++;}return w;}return p.get(0)+h+"wicka";};}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class p {
    Function<String, String> b = s -> {
        List<String> p = Arrays.asList(s.split("(?=[A-Z])"));

        if (!s.matches("[^A-Z]*[A-Z].+")) {
            String w = "";

            int i = 0;

            for (char c : String.join("", s).toCharArray()) {
                w += String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, Character.toString(c)));

                i++;
            }

            return w;
        }

        String h = "-";

        List<List<String>> k;

        if (p.size() != 1) {
            k = Lists.partition(p, 2);

            String w = String.join("", k.get(0)) + h + String.join(h, Collections.nCopies(k.get(0).size(), "wicka")) + h + String.join(h,    Collections.nCopies(k.get(1).size(), "wub")) + h;

            int i = String.join("", k.get(0)).length();

            for (char c : String.join("", k.get(1)).toCharArray()) {
                w += String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, Character.toString(c)));

                i++;
            }
            return w;
        }

        return p.get(0) + h + "wicka";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin 1.1 - <s>494</s> 492 bytes

### Submission

```
typealias S=String
fun Iterable<*>.j(s:S="")=this.joinToString(s)
fun s(s:S):S{var c=0
val m=mutableListOf<S>()
var t=""
s.map{if(it.isUpperCase()){c+=1
if(t!=""){m.add(t)
t=""}}
t+=it}
if(c==0)return e(s,1)
m.add(t)
val p=Math.ceil(m.size/2.0).toInt()
val f=m.subList(0,p)
val z=m.subList(p,m.size)
val w=List(f.size,{"wicka"})
val u=List(z.size,{"wub"})
val x=f.j()
var v="-"+(w+u).j("-")
if(c>1)v+="-"
return x+v+e(z.j(),x.length)}
fun e(s:S,o:Int)=s.mapIndexed{c,i->List(c+o,{i}).j()}.j()
```

### Test

```
typealias S=String
fun Iterable<*>.j(s:S="")=this.joinToString(s)
fun s(s:S):S{var c = 0
val m=mutableListOf<S>()
var t=""
s.map{if(it.isUpperCase()){c+=1
if(t!=""){m.add(t)
t=""}}
t+=it}
if(c==0)return e(s,1)
m.add(t)
val p=Math.ceil(m.size/2.0).toInt()
val f=m.subList(0,p)
val z=m.subList(p,m.size)
val w=List(f.size,{"wicka"})
val u=List(z.size,{"wub"})
val x=f.j()
var v="-"+(w+u).j("-")
if(c>1)v+="-"
return x+v+e(z.j(),x.length)}
fun e(s:S,o:Int)=s.mapIndexed{c,i->List(c+o,{i}).j()}.j()

data class TestData(val input: String, val output: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val tests = listOf(
            TestData("DJMcMayhem", "DJ-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-MMcccMMMMaaaaayyyyyyhhhhhhheeeeeeeemmmmmmmmm"),
            TestData("PPCG", "PP-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-CCGGG"),
            TestData("foobarbaz", "fooooobbbbaaaaarrrrrrbbbbbbbaaaaaaaazzzzzzzzz"),
            TestData("FooBarBaz", "FooBar-wicka-wicka-wub-BBBBBBaaaaaaazzzzzzzz"),
            TestData("HelloWorld", "Hello-wicka-wub-WWWWWoooooorrrrrrrllllllllddddddddd"),
            TestData("Test", "Test-wicka"),
            TestData("UPPER", "UPP-wicka-wicka-wicka-wub-wub-EEERRRR"),
            TestData("fooBarBaz", "fooBar-wicka-wicka-wub-BBBBBBaaaaaaazzzzzzzz")
    )

    for (test in tests) {
        var out = s(test.input)
        if (out != test.output) {
            System.err.println("TEST FAILED")
            System.err.println("IN  " + test.input)
            System.err.println("EXP " + test.output)
            System.err.println("OUT " + out)
            return
        }
    }
    println("Test Passed")
}
```

### Running

Works on KotlinLang, but not on TryItOnline as 1.1 is not supported

*Ran through my compressor, saved 2 bytes*

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 64 bytes

```
ꜝ[`(?=[A-Z])`ṡḢ:₅½⌈:‟ẎDƛ`≤ȧka-`;∑$∑‹p^ȯ:ƛ‛≤¶;‹∑∇∑f:ẏ∇∇∑L+*÷|ėvΠ÷
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%AA&code=%EA%9C%9D%5B%60%28%3F%3D%5BA-Z%5D%29%60%E1%B9%A1%E1%B8%A2%3A%E2%82%85%C2%BD%E2%8C%88%3A%E2%80%9F%E1%BA%8ED%C6%9B%60%E2%89%A4%C8%A7ka-%60%3B%E2%88%91%24%E2%88%91%E2%80%B9p%5E%C8%AF%3A%C6%9B%E2%80%9B%E2%89%A4%C2%B6%3B%E2%80%B9%E2%88%91%E2%88%87%E2%88%91f%3A%E1%BA%8F%E2%88%87%E2%88%87%E2%88%91L%2B*%C3%B7%7C%C4%97v%CE%A0%C3%B7&inputs=DJMcMayhem&header=&footer=)

Since the stack manipulation is quite complex, I've added a representation of the stack after each step.

```
ꜝ[             # If any letters are uppercase (example input: DJMcMayhem
  `(?=[A-Z])`ṡ # Split before uppercase letters
               # [['','D','J','Mc','Mayhem']]

Ḣ                  # Lop off the first value
                   # [['D','J','Mc','Mayhem']]
 :₅½⌈              # Duplicate and push ceil(length/2)
                   # [['D','J','Mc','Mayhem'],['D','J','Mc','Mayhem'],2]
     :‟Ẏ           # Push a copy on the bottom and slice from the start
                   # [2,['D','J','Mc','Mayhem'],['D','J']]
        Dƛ`≤ȧka-`; # Triplicate and fill one copy with 'wicka-'
                   # [2,['D','J','Mc','Mayhem'],['D','J'],['D','J'],['wicka-','wicka-']]

∑$∑             # Sum these and sum the pair under that
                # [2,['D','J','Mc','Mayhem'],['D','J'],'wicka-wicka-','DJ']
   ‹p           # Add a hyphen and prepend
                # [2,['D','J','Mc','Mayhem'],['D','J'],'DJ-wicka-wicka-']
     ^ȯ         # Reverse the stack and slice
                # ['DJ-wicka-wicka-',['D','J'],['Mc','Mayhem']]
       :ƛ‛≤¶;‹∑ # Duplicate, fill a copy with 'wub-' and sum that
                # ['DJ-wicka-wicka-',['D','J'],['Mc','Mayhem'],'wub-wub-']

∇∑f          # Shift and turn the full second half into a list of characters
             # ['DJ-wicka-wicka-','wub-wub-',['D','J'],['M','c','M','a','y','h','e','m']]
   :ẏ        # Duplicate and make a range of 0...length
             # ['DJ-wicka-wicka-','wub-wub-',['D','J'],['M','c','M','a','y','h','e','m'],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
     ∇∇∑L+   # Get the full length of the first half and add it to each item of this range
             # ['DJ-wicka-wicka-','wub-wub-',['M','c','M','a','y','h','e','m'],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
          *÷ # Multiply (repeat) (vectorising) and iterate out over the stack
             # ['DJ-wicka-wicka-','wub-wub-','MM','ccc','MMMM','aaaaa','yyyyyy','hhhhhhh','eeeeeeee','mmmmmmmmm']
             # Then the Ṫ flag smash-prints this.
         

|     # Else...
 ė    # Enumerate (zip with range to length)
  vΠ  # Reduce each by multiplication
    ÷ # Iterate (push each to the stack)
      # Then the Ṫ flag smash-prints this.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>234</s> <s>281</s> <s>270</s> <s>248</s> 246 bytes

```python
s,j=input(),"".join;f=lambda l,n:j(c*i for i,c in enumerate(j(l),n));import re;u=re.split("([A-Z])",s);l=len(u)
m=[j(u[i:i+2])for i in range(1,l,2)];i=-~l//4;d=j(m[:i]);print((j([d+"-wicka"*i+"-wub"*(l//2-i)+"-",f(m[i:],len(d))]),f(u[0],1))[l<2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BUsQgEETvfgXFaSZLdt3oKcjB35DiQBLiDhJIESjLi78eE2/dXd391p/ySPFl3zfhFcW1FkDB@dUninJWwS7DZFkQsfcwNsTmlBmJkVFkLtbFZVsceAgoIqKkZU25sOxkVdldtzVQAQ76vf0wyMWGMqjgIlR8WpT2UDX1dOkM/t@ep9nGTwd3EUSHRpJqf8Pt9ion5WHRPRmUa6ZY4GDq6cLbbxq/LG/olHXgDRz1riU8PBfzsaHeiBM5IRo8kqqfjbgj6vB2cPd9TmmwNv8B)

*Added 47 bytes, thanks to Mr. Xcoder ;)*

*Saved 11 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech*

*Saved 22 bytes thanks to Halvard Hummel*

*Saved 2 more bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder*

Comment: Fails for `foobar`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Fixed!

Comment: *Added 47 bytes, thanks to Mr. Xcoder ;)* >_>

Comment: Possible [270 bytes](https://goo.gl/2FBHxz).

Comment: [248 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY2xboQwEET7fAVytQvmCCQVjotIqSLdD8RywYHJrWMbZGxF9/UE0s2MNO@tj3Rfwsu@b9xKCmtOgJyxi10oiFm6wd@moXA89BbGkop5iQXxsaBQmJC9iUMyYMEhD4iC/LrEVEQjsozmsq2OEjBQ7/WXRsY3FE46EyDjk5fKQlbUU9Vp/Mee0DiEbwMtd7xDLUiCq1psmlcxSQte9aRRrJFCgsOqporVvzT@DKykM@YbK8E1TVcTHp3x@fhQr/kpnRA1HktWz5q3iMq9HeZ9//i8jtfhcTf@Dw)

Comment: [246 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY2xbsMgGIT3PgVi4ndw0riZTBkqdaqUFyhiIDZufgrYwqAqS1/dxd3uTnf3LY98n@PLtq3cSYxLyQw4pUc3YxST9CbcRkM8j71jQ4NkmhNBPhCMxMYSbDLZMsc88AggMCxzyiRZUWSyx3XxmBll6q391ED5CsJLbyMr8BSkcqwo7PHQafi/3U@TiV@WnbnnHWiBsv31p9NFjNKxoHrUIJaEMbPKVOOBtj84fBva4C7LjTas1rsWoXrKp7rBXvMdOQJoqElRz5qfAZR/rdxte/@4DlfzuNvwBw)